Find a biholomorphic map from $G = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ |z| = 1, \, \Im z > 0 \}$ to $\Omega = \{ |z| > 1 \}$, where $\infty$ is fixed.
Find a biholomorphic map from
$G = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ |z| = 1, \, \Im z > 0 \}$ to $\Omega = \{ |z| > 1 \}$,
where $\infty$ is fixed.
I am not really sure where to even start, one thing that really confuses me here is the fact that I could use $z^2$ to get the complacent of $G$ to the entire unit circle (except $\{-1,1\}$) and from there I want to transform it into ${|z|\leq 1}$ but while searching online I saw that one cannot take the unit disk and a biholomorphic between it and the unit circle so I cant do that thing apparently so I dont know what to do.
Any hints would be very much appreciated!
